# Python Index function ignoring matching items

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I have a variable str (`a='ZpglnRxqenU'`). I am trying to get a printout of this str by item along with that item's index. But when running a simple for loop:

```
for i in a:
    print(i,a.index(i))
```

the printout is as follows(I have bolded the error I am getting)

```
Z 0
p 1
g 2
l 3
n 4
R 5
x 6
q 7
e 8
**n 4**
U 10
```

Why does this second n not index as 9? Is there a way to get the second in to properly index to 9?

note* I have also tried running a as a list and got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation states (the situation for strings is similar)

> list.index(x)
>
> Return the index in the list of the **first item** whose
>   value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

That's why all `n`s will evaluate to 4 (the lowest position of any `n` in the list/string).

You could do:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    print(val, idx)
```